# collectIng identical rows of an np array by list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy, grouping, rows

I have a 2d np array and want to collect identical rows by list comprehension.
My implementation returns the desired result and a better solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532983/finding-identical-rows-and-columns-in-a-numpy-array):

```py
import numpy as np


A = np.array([ 
        [1,1,1,0,0,0],  #sample input data
        [0,0,1,0,1,1],
        [0,0,1,0,1,1],
        [1,1,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,1,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,0,1,0],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0]   
])




def gr_id_rows(Matrix):  #returns list of lists of identical row indices

  m = Matrix.shape[0]
  M = Matrix
  indices = list(range(m))
  lst_of_lsts_ident = []

  while len(M) > 0:
    lst_ident = []
    row_0 = M[0,:]
    M = np.delete(M, 0, 0)
    lst_ident.append(indices.pop(0))
    
    k = 0
    for row in M:
      if np.array_equal(row, row_0):
        M = np.delete(M, k, 0)
        lst_ident.append(indices.pop(k))
      else:
        k += 1

    lst_of_lsts_ident.append(lst_ident)    

  return lst_of_lsts_ident



#execution
print( gr_id_rows(A) )   #[[0, 3], [1, 2, 4], [5, 8], [6], [7]]
```

Notes about the real dataset:

- It's binary only.
- Size can go up to about 1000 x 700 but will mostly be around 60 x 40.

Can we do this elegantly by using list comprehension?

I made an attempt that (obviously) yields a wrong result.

```py
nbr_rows = A.shape[0]
col_ind = range(A.shape[0])

ind_eq = [[k for k in col_ind if np.array_equal(A[k,:], A[h,:]) and k != h] for h in col_ind] 


print(ind_eq) #[[3], [2, 4], [1, 4], [0], [1, 2], [8], [], [], [5]]
```

Comment: I don't know if the NumPy API provides a fancy way of doing this. For an array of that size, you could probably use traditional methods, e.g. treating your 2d `A` array as a list of lists

Comment: Thanks Brad Solomon, your link shows some simpler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `numpy.equal` on A versus itself (broadcasted), and `itertools.groupby` to reshape the output:

```
from itertools import groupby
a,b = np.equal(A, A[:,None]).all(2).nonzero()
{tuple(b[i] for i in g) for i,g in groupby(range(len(a)), lambda i:a[i])}
```

output:

```
{(0, 3), (1, 2, 4), (5, 8), (6,), (7,)}
```